# Understanding lemma 13.2 in Topology by Munkres : Why do I need to show that it generates the same topology?

Tags: general-topology

Munkres states the following lemma in his *Topology*:

Lemma 13.2: Let $X$ be a topological space and suppose $K$ is a collection of open sets of $X$ such that for each open set $U$ of $X$ and each $x$ in $U$, there is an element $C$ of $K$ such that $x\in C\subset U$. Then $K$ is a basis for the topology of X.

I have shown that 1) Given $x \in X$ there is some open set in $K$ containing $x$.(2)Given $x\in C_1,C_2 \in K$, there is an open set $C \in K$ such that $x\in K \subset C_1 \cap C_2$.

Question: Shouldn't this be enough to prove that $K$ is a basis for the topological space $X$? After all, Munkres defines a basis as a collection of subsets of $X$ satisfying properties (1) and (2). Why do I need to show that that the topology generated by $K$ is the same as the given one?

Comment: In the book, the first paragraph of the proof shows that $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis. But a basis for $what$ space? A basis for some $Y$, $Z$ ? We must verify that it is a basis for *$X$*, and this is the content of the second paragraph f the proof.

Comment: Ok, I am a little confused now. In the definition (and I just noticed it), he says that if X is a set, a basis for a topology on X is a collection $\beta$ satisfying (1)  Given $x \in X$ there is a $B \in \beta$ containing $x$.(2)Given $x\in C_1,C_2 \in \beta$, there exists a $C \in \beta$ such that $x\in C \subset C_1 \cap C_2$. So, I don't see how the basis needs a topological space. (It should but I don't see how the definition demands it)

Comment: I've written up an answer. @user96343

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read carefully the paragraph following the definition of basis on page$78$:

> If $\mathcal{B}$ satisfies these two conditions, then we define the **topology $\mathcal{T}$ generated by $\mathcal{B}$** as follows: A subset $U$ of $X$ is said to be ope in $X$ (that is, to be an element of $\mathcal{T}$) if for each $x\in U$, there is a basis element $B\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B$ and $B\subset U$. Note that each basis element is itself an element of $\mathcal{T}$.

In plain English, the whole definition and the paragraph says: Ok now, given the set $X$, let's define a topology on $X$ by a new trick: we specify which sets are open in $X$ indirectly in terms of basis. Once we have a basis on $X$ first, then we can define a topology $\mathcal{T}$ as follows: A subset $U$ of $X$ is said to be open in $X$ if……blah blah…...

So the definition has **not** predefined any topology on $X$. 
(The language of the definition is indeed prone to cause confusions. I remember I had struggle with it for a while when I was reading that as well) It just presents you a new trick to define topologies on $X$.

Now, in practice, often we *already* know some topology on $X$, and we would like to know:

> Is there any basis that generates the topology we have?

So we want to go into the *other* direction. We would like to know that our old familiar topology  indeed comes from this "new trick". Once we have verified that $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis, it *automatically* generates a topology $\mathcal{T}'$. But is it the product we want? Is it the same as our old $\mathcal{T}$? This is a nontrivial fact to be checked.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I understand it now. So, each time I see a question of the form "Is B a basis for top. space X?", I should read it as "Does it satisfy properties (1) and (2) and generate the same topology?". Right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This question is of practical importance because we might be able to find some $\mathcal{B}$ that has some nice properties, for example, being countable. Once we can prove that this nice $\mathcal{B}$ does indeed generate the already-defined topology, then we know that the space $X$ at hand is *second countable* (see page $190$), and this can greatly simplifies the proofs of the many desired properties we want for the space $X$.